# Chef install local apt_package with dependencies

Tags: linux, debian, chef

I try to install my locally baked package on server:

```
cookbook_file '/var/cache/apt/archives/nfdhcpd_0.20_all.deb' do
  source 'nfdhcpd_0.20_all.deb'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0755'
  action :create
end
package 'nfdhcpd_0.20_all.deb' do
    provider Chef::Provider::Package::Dpkg
    source "/var/cache/apt/archives/nfdhcpd_0.20_all.deb"
    action :install
end
```

I need to use `dpkg provider` because `apt provider` doesn't support local packages (`apt package provider cannot handle source attribute. Use dpkg provider instead`). I've got an error (missing deps):

```
STDERR: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nfdhcpd:
 nfdhcpd depends on python-scapy (>= 2.0.1-1); however:
  Package python-scapy is not installed.
```

How can I tell chef to install missing dependencies? (without manually installing them)

Comment: what happens if you issue the `dpkg` command without chef?

Comment: Without chef I would use a `apt-get -f install` to install missing deps and rerun dpkg.

Comment: If you bypass apt, you lose dependency functionality, so you'd have to do it manually. It's what apt is for, right?

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg` cannot install dependencies, so you need to create a local apt repository containing your package. https://askubuntu.com/a/176546 gives the basic idea. You need to put a `Packages` file along with your `.deb` and then refer to that directory in a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

```
file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/local-apt.list' do
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode '0644'
    content "deb file:/var/cache/apt/archives/ ./"
    action :create
    notifies :run, 'execute[apt-get update]', :immediately
end

package 'nfdhcpd'
```

Answer (score 0):

What about passing the `-f` as an option?

[Install a package with options](https://docs.chef.io/resource_package.html)

> ```
> package 'debian-archive-keyring' do
>   action :install
>   options '--force-yes'
> end
> ```

[apt_package](https://docs.chef.io/resource_apt_package.html)

> ```
> apt_package 'name' do
>   default_release            String
>   notifies                   # see description
>   options                    String
>   package_name               String, Array # defaults to 'name' if not specified
>   provider                   Chef::Provider::Package::Apt
>   source                     String
>   subscribes                 # see description
>   timeout                    String, Integer
>   version                    String, Array
>   action                     Symbol # defaults to :install if not specified
> end
> ```

[dpkg_package](https://docs.chef.io/resource_dpkg_package.html)

> ```
> dpkg_package 'name' do
>   notifies                   # see description
>   options                    String
>   package_name               String, Array # defaults to 'name' if not specified
>   provider                   Chef::Provider::Package::Dpkg
>   source                     String
>   subscribes                 # see description
>   timeout                    String, Integer
>   version                    String, Array
>   action                     Symbol # defaults to :install if not specified
> end
> ```
>
> options
>
> Ruby Type: String
>
> One (or more) additional options that are passed to the command.

Comment: Hey, `-f` in apt-get means `--fix-broken` not `--force*`. It won't work - apt_package cannot install local packages (only from repo), dpkg_package has no option `--force-yes`